# Is it possible to see variable states in native iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, scope, system-variable

For example, if upon launching my app I wanted to see who the current caller was or what the latest SMS message was from "Phone" or "Messages", are there classes available that can access information at this level?

This may be a system security/stability/scoping issue that Apple wants to avoid, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assumptions are correct, this is not currently allowed, nor do I think it ever will be.

I believe their reasoning for this is so developers cannot access personal information like phone numbers and addresses and exploit them.

You can send mail and SMS messages from with the app, and you can see the current call state.

Comment: You can access contact information through the Address Book API.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. The user can access contact information through the Address API but you cannot interact with user contacts outside of that API.

Comment: Maximus gracimus. Would you mind sharing how to see the current call state?

Comment: Go into the documentation, search for the Core Telephony framework. There's two classes for you, CTCall and CTCallCenter. I think you'll find your answers there. Most (if not all) methods are iOS 4.0+.

Comment: Much appreciated. Will explore further.

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is right, that it's a system security issue. Apple does not give access to such information, since it's definitely a breach of privacy. Sorry.